# trying to mach sentence with multi lines without using modifier (s)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i'm trying to catch a sentence between to tags for example

```
#<b>(.+)</b>#is

<b>sentense</b>
```

but the problem when i add new line i cant catch it.

i tried to use modifier s but when i use multi b tags it catch first b tag

and last close b tag

for example :

```
<b>hello every one </b> are you great <b>i hope you so</b>
```

it will catch from

```
hello every one </b> are you great <b>i hope you so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: `#<b>(.+?)</b>#is`

The ? makes it non-greedy.

Comment: I think you mean `(.+?)`.  The way you have it, the `?` is a "zero or one" quantifier.  So `(.+)?` matches one or more characters, or it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, just came back to this.  Try that Turki Alhazaa.  Thanks Alan Moore.